# How to find a bug in a WDF driver that causes a BSOD on Windows 8

Tags: windows, wdf

I have to maintain a WDF driver. This is a no-hardware driver: the driver use a disk file which is mounted as a Windows partition. All the data written to the disk are encrypted by the driver. The driver run in kernel mode.

The driver has been developed on XP and successfully ported on Vista and 7, 32 & 64 bits. I encounter one big problem on Windows 8. The driver lead to a fatal system error:

```
BugCheck 50, {ffffffffffffffd0, 0, fffff800002de33a, 0}
Probably caused by : Wdf01000.sys ( Wdf01000!FxDevice::DispatchWithLock+fa )
```

The problem occurs after deleting the device with WdfObjectDelete(). As long as the device is not deleted the driver run fine and there is no system error. When WdfObjectDelete has been called, the system crashes after a certain delay.

**verifier** detects no error in the driver. My questions are the following:

1. Is there anything special regarding WDF on Windows 8?
2. Is there any tool/technique that could help me finding the bug in the driver?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be anything specific to Windows 8 for this issue. I'd recommend starting to [debug your driver with WinDbg via a remote system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). With this you can set breakpoints, step through the code and most importantly get post-mortem information on the crash. Once you have connected a machine, and you can see they crash use `analyze -v` to get information. [OSR is a great resource for BSOD debugging](http://osronline.com/).

Comment: [This article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6302.windows-bugcheck-analysis.aspx) is a good resource on bug check analysis.